# lmer nested design estimating variance of one level as zero

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have data from a series of psychology experiments in which human subjects completed one of many tasks. Multiple observations are taken per subject. Finally, tasks can be divided into one of two types. I would like to fit a model with a fixed effect for type of task, and then random intercepts for task and subject. Below are simulated data, with the lmer model I am trying to fit.

```
N = 1000
subject = rep(rnorm(N/2), each=2)             # two obs per subject
task = rep(rnorm(10, sd=.5), each=N/10)       # 10 tasks
error = rnorm(N, sd=.25)
type = rep(c(1, 5), each=N/2)                 # fixed effects of 1 or 5
dv = subject + task + type + error


df = data.frame(subject = rep(1:(N/2), each=2), 
                task    = rep(letters[1:10], each=N/10),
                type    = rep(c('x','y'), each=N/2),
                dv      = dv
)

fit = lmer(dv ~ type + (1 | task:subject) + (1 | task), data=df)
```

Here, the outputs of `lmer` are consistent with the parameters set in the simulation.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: dv ~ type + (1 | task:subject) + (1 | task)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 1851.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0617 -0.4636  0.0018  0.4857  2.4420 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 task:subject (Intercept) 0.93276  0.9658  
 task         (Intercept) 0.20511  0.4529  
 Residual                 0.06843  0.2616  
Number of obs: 1000, groups:  task:subject, 500; task, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   1.0859     0.2119   5.125
typey         3.9994     0.2996  13.348

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr)
typey -0.707
```

When I fit my data without the fixed-effect, it estimates the variance for `task:subject` and `task`..

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: ACC.ser ~ (1 | task:subid) + (1 | task)
   Data: dat.sub

REML criterion at convergence: -350.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.84997 -0.55776  0.01604  0.53404  2.03947 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 task:subid (Intercept) 0.023145 0.15214 
 task       (Intercept) 0.003473 0.05893 
 Residual               0.008479 0.09208 

...
```

However, when I add in the fixed effect to the model, the variance estimate for task becomes 0. Moreover, when I examine the intercepts for task, they're all 0 as well. What disparities could be causing the addition of the fixed effect in `lmer` to reduce variance estimates to 0? Task is nested within type, as in the simulation. I'm happy to clarify any details that might be useful.